# orgtbl-to-html within HTML document

Tags: org-export, org-table

I'm learning emacs now and I've run into a problem.
I would like to use `orgtbl` minor-mode within an HTML file and be able to update the contents of the org table as HTML code directly.

I saw an YouTube video and got interested to do so. But I don't know how. Here is my code as entered in emacs.
[image]

I do not know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc for this quite nice feature is in [Appendix A](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax.html#Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax) of org manual and says (emphasis mine):

> **Just above the source table**, we put a special line that tells Orgtbl
>   mode how to translate this table and where to install it.  For example:
>
> ```
> #+ORGTBL: SEND table_name translation_function arguments...
> ```

So you need to remove the blank line between the `#+ORGTBL:` and the table itself.  Typing `C-c C-c` with point in the table does update html code in the `RECEIVE ORGTBL` area.

Command `orgtbl-insert-radio-table` inserts a skeleton, avoiding this kind of problems.